Bundle.js not found - webpack configuration for different environments
I'm facing an issue with my react application. I use webpack and for some reason the bundle.js that is being generated inside the dist folder is not being loaded on my QA environment. (it load normally on local). So, let's step by step on my app:
folder structure:
[] ccweb
  [] dist
  [] node_modules
  [] public
  [] src
  - .babelrc
  - .gitignore
  - ecosystem.json
  - package-lock.json
  - package.json
  - server.js
  - webpack.config.js

For development purposes, I ran the code locally and it doesn't use the server.js file. When the code runs in another environment (QA or Production), it uses the server.js to create the https server (servers are using PM2 to run the code). Inside of this server.js there is the express information, but one thing that I thought would be important for this issue is this two lines:
app.use("/ccweb", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist"), { etag: false, lastModified: false}));
app.use("/assets", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "dist", "assets"), { etag: false, lastModified: false}));

There is also this information:
    if (req.url == "/" || req.originalUrl == "/" | !req.url.startsWith("ccweb")) {
       res.redirect("ccweb/login");
    } else {
       res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/dist/index.html"));
    }

So what is actually happening:
Accessing http://localhost:8001 works completely normal, load the bundle.js and the assets images correctly.
But when I do the QA deploy and try to access https:<MY_QA_URL>/ccweb it just doesn't find the bundle.js file. It tries to get the bundle.js from https:<MY_QA_URL>/bundle.js instead of https:<MY_QA_URL>/ccweb/bundle.js.
My webpack configuration is like this:
const config = {
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "/",
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'index.html',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                resolve: {
                    fallback: {
                        "http": require.resolve("stream-http"),          // install 'stream-http'
                        "https": require.resolve("https-browserify"),   // install 'https-browserify'
                        "vm": require.resolve("vm-browserify"),         // install 'os-browserify'
                        "os": require.resolve("os-browserify/browser"), // install 'vm-browserify'
                        "buffer": require.resolve("buffer/"),            // install 'buffer'
                        "url": false,
                        "constants": false,
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ["@babel/preset-env", {
                                targets: [
                                    "last 2 versions",
                                    "ie 11",
                                    "not dead",
                                    "> 0.5%"
                                ]
                            }],
                            "@babel/preset-react"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [stylesHandler, 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/i,
                use: [stylesHandler, 'css-loader', 'less-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|gif)$/i,
                type: 'asset',
            },
        ],
    },
};

my index.html is referencing the bundle.js like this:
<script src="/bundle.js"></script>

So, does anyone have a clue on what could be wrong in my application that makes QA url not find the bundle js?

Try ./bundle.js

Hi, that works if I'm not using more than one level deep on my url. But if use for example: http://localhost:8000/reset/forgot the same issue happens, it doesn't find the bundle.js
